# Bake sound to f curve on Geometry Node via Python API

Tags: python, animation, blender, modeling, bpy

I'm creating a script that loads a bunch of a audio files, for each audio file I want it to:

1. Place the audio on the sequence
2. Set the frames of the animation equal to the length of the audio
3. Bake the audio to f curve on 2 different Geometry nodes. I'm very new to Blender and this is the state I expect via GUI:

[image]

4. Render as animation

This is my code so far:

```
import bpy
import os

input_directory = ...
output_directory = ...

# Get a list of all audio files in the directory
audio_files = [file for file in os.listdir(input_directory) if file.endswith(".wav")][:1]

print(f"found {len(audio_files)} files to process")

# Set render settings
bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'FFMPEG'
bpy.context.scene.render.ffmpeg.format = 'MPEG4'
bpy.context.scene.render.ffmpeg.audio_codec = 'AAC'

bpy.context.area.type = 'SEQUENCE_EDITOR'

def bake_node(node_name, audio_path):
    bpy.context.area.type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bpy.context.space_data.tree_type = 'GeometryNodeTree'
    
    if bpy.context.space_data.node_tree:
        node = bpy.context.space_data.node_tree.nodes.get(node_name)
        
        if node:
            print('found node: ', node)
            bpy.context.space_data.node_tree.nodes.active = node
            bpy.context.area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR'
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = node
            bpy.ops.graph.sound_bake(filepath=audio_path, low=1, high=250, bake=True)
    else:
        print("Node tree not found in the Geometry Nodes workspace.")
        

# Loop through each audio file and load it into the sequencer
for idx, audio_file in enumerate(audio_files):
    # Add an audio strip to the sequencer
    audio_path = filepath=os.path.join(input_directory, audio_file)
    bpy.ops.sequencer.sound_strip_add(audio_path, frame_start=1, channel=1)
    
    bake_node("bake_target_2", audio_path)
    output_filename = f"animation_{audio_file}_{idx+1}.mp4"
    

    # Render the animation
    # bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = os.path.join(output_directory, output_filename)
    # bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True, write_still=True)

    # Remove the audio strip from the sequencer
    bpy.ops.sequencer.delete()
```

So far I've found the docs pretty useless and there's no clear path forward. Maybe some help explaining how the api maps to graphical elements?